# Is it bad to use concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor for multiprocessing?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

One of my friend told me that I have a performance bug in below code snippet. He told me to use `map` or `imap` instead. I can't  understand what is wrong. Should I use `multiprocessing` package instead? How it can be improved?

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = list(future.result() for future in
                          [ executor.submit(do_something, id) for id in [1,2,3] ])
```

Comment: What did your friend say is the problem?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi He told me I should not use future as it does not fully utilize cpu. He told me to use map or imap instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ProcessPoolExecutor documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor), ProcessPoolExecutor uses the multiprocessing module already.

> The ProcessPoolExecutor class is an Executor subclass that uses a pool of processes to execute calls asynchronously. ProcessPoolExecutor uses the multiprocessing module, which allows it to side-step the Global Interpreter Lock but also means that only picklable objects can be executed and returned.

Comment: So, Is it perfectly fine to use as it is? What if I use executor.map() instead of submit?

Comment: In the question code, `future.result()` is called after all futures have been created. All futures are thus run in parallel without blocking; only fetching the results happens in a blocking manner.